# Ubuntu Server 20.04 on Raspberry Pi 4 error: "kernel: ieee80211 phy0: brcmf_cfg80211_get_station: GET STA INFO failed, -52" How to fix?

Tags: wifi, ubuntu, kernel, logfiles

I am running Ubuntu Server 20.04 on a Raspberry Pi 4. In my system logs I am getting the followng error:

```
kernel: ieee80211 phy0: brcmf_cfg80211_get_station: GET STA INFO failed, -52
```

What does this mean and how can I fix it so it doesn't fail?

Answer (score 0):

Also experiencing this on custom board with fmac43430. Doing "rmmod brcmfmac && modprobe brcmfmac" helps as a temporary workaround

Comment: Thanks. But do you have any idea what these commands do and what the error means or is indicating?